# Is there a limit to the amount of questions one can post in a given time frame?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am in the process of writing my thesis and have managed to run into a lot of issues along the way. To stop me procrastinating on tex.SX, I jot a note down at the time but don't actually post the question.

As I am nearing my submission, I will have to resolve a lot of these issues though. While there seems to be no issue with me [asking multiple questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2933/14210) as long as I do not [flood the front page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2934/14210) and they are of decent quality (MWE included, of course), I found an older discussion about instituting [posting limits](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1617/14210). The answers there advocate a limit of [one question per day](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1639/14210) (accepted answer) or [30 low quality questions a month](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1623/14210) (highest voted answer).

While I have less than 30 questions to ask, and I intend to put the same time and effort into them as befits the site (a lot, in case anyone's wondering), I might certainly post more than one a day.

So the question is, have any of those proposed limits been implemented and, if so, what are those limits.

Judging by the lack of "Why can't I post anymore?" rants on meta, I'm guessing the answer is no, but it's also good information to record for the next person who has qualms about flooding the site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/168244) is a go-to source for generic answers to this type of question. From there you're find [Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4359/168244) Here are some quotes from that answer (for completeness):

> A user may ask only...
>
> - [50 questions over any 30-day period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217/168244)
> - [six questions over any 24-hour period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90470/168244)
> - one question over any 30-second period
> - [users with less than 125 reputation can only post questions every 20 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66844/168244)
>
> The 30-day limit was introduced on 29 April 2011, and at the moment of writing it only applies to Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User. Beware that deleting existing questions will probably not circumvent this limit, and [may actually make things worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86982/168244).
>
> The 30-second and "only post questions every 20 minutes" limits are anti-spam/bot measures.

Comment: Phew, I think egreg and I have just managed to stay below those limits.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, since all these limits deal with *questions*. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Werner, it didn't even dawn on me to check the overall SE guidelines once I found those questions on meta.